# Perfect Block tips

Tags: infinity-blade-2

While I collect Perfect Parries easily, I still have to get even one Perfect Block. I realize this is a timing issue (or so I believe), but would appreciate any tips/guidance/links to other sources how to add Perfect Blocks to my fights. I play on an iPhone 5 with most recent iOS.

Comment: umm... like you said. it's all timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tricks, it's a simple question of timing and practice. Every enemy's attack has its own animation so the timing is different for each of them :

- Perfect block require a last moment block
- Just feel the moment you're going to get hit by the attack and block a split second before.
- If you get hit, just tap block a little sooner the next time
- Once you've practiced enough you should feel the timing and manage perfect block 90% of the time